# How to use HTMLMediaElement.srcObject = stream

Tags: html, video, streaming, media-player

I've been scouring the web and S/O for answers as to why the following code does not work, but so far no dice. It is supposed to simply stream the user's video and audio. I am viewing it in Chrome.

```
<html>
<body>
  <video width="400" height="400" id="userVideo"></video>
<script>
var userStream;
if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                //both video and audio
                  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: true,
                  }, function(stream) {
                      console.log("got the stream");
                      userStream = stream;

                      document.getElementById("userVideo").srcObject = userStream;

                  });
              }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding `autoplay="true"` in the video tag

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue -- figured out with some fiddling from the example here (https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) -- is that I had to put an autoplay attribute in the html video tag.

Answer (score 0):

give this a go:

```js
var userStream;
if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video:true}).then(function(stream) {
          console.log("got the stream");
                      userStream = stream;

                 document.getElementById("userVideo").srcObject = userStream;

          });
              }
```

this one runs for me in Chrome

Comment: Nope. Also doesn't work for me, even though I know it's not an issue with either my computer or WebRTC implementation, because https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ works.