# JS : modifying "srcObject" attribute or "src" attribute of the html <video>?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mediastream

Im looking for to way to show my webcam on a web page. (Learning purposes)
I tried these codes :

```html
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024 initial-scale=1">
        <!--JS-->
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <p>just a webpage to insert JS and see console returns</p>
            <video id="retourUtilisateur" autoplay playsinline></video>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const contraintes = {
    video: {
    width: {
        min: 1280,
        ideal: 1920,
        max: 2560,
    },
    height: {
        min: 720,
        ideal: 1080,
        max: 1440
    },
    }
};

//is getUserMedia available ?
if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
    console.log("Fonctionalités logicielles disponibles")
}
else(console.log("Fonctionalités logicielles indisponibles"))

//asking for camera access
try {
    const stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(contraintes);
    console.log("cam connected");
    // Utiliser le stream ici

    // Affichage du stream
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const video = document.getElementById("retourUtilisateur");
        video.srcObject = stream;
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Impossible d'accéder à la caméra", e);
}
```

it's, at a few details, the same thing I saw [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308691/how-to-use-htmlmediaelement-srcobject-stream).

But I've an error in console : caught TypeError: Failed to set the 'srcObject' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided value is not of type '(MediaSourceHandle or MediaStream)'.

So... I checked Mozila datasheet, and... it's right, html  do not have a srcObject attribute. So how in the world are these exemples working ? what am I missing ? I continued with this datasheet, and replaced my srcObject attribute by a src attribute. my error changed for : "GET [http://127.0.0.1:5500/[object%20Promise]](http://127.0.0.1:5500/%5Bobject%20Promise%5D) 404 (Not Found)" but... why have I a 404 error ? isn't it only when a web page is missing ? And I do not understand why it's speaking about a promise. What it is ?

Seeya

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is of type `Promise<MediaStream>`. In order to access the object, you would need to await the Promise using the `await` syntax or `.then` and pass a callback function.

Here are two ways you could try out.

1. Using `.then`

```js
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia(contraintes)
  .then((stream) => {
    console.log("cam connected");
    let video = document.getElementById("retourUtilisateur");

    if (stream && video) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Impossible d'accéder à la caméra", e);
  });
```

2. Using `await`

```
let video = document.getElementById("retourUtilisateur");

async function getStream() {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(contraintes);
  return stream;
}
(async () => {
  try {
    const stream = await getStream();
    console.log("Camera connected");

    if (stream && video) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Impossible d'accéder à la caméra", e);
  }
})();
```

Note: You could add `defer` to the script tag when loading your javascript instead of using the event listener to wait for the DOM content to load.

Here are some resources in case you need to look up more information.

References:

1. [Promises - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#description)
2. [HTMLMediaElement (part of video element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject)
3. [srcObj browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#browser_compatibility)
4. [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)